# Logo selection for poster presentation

Tags: affiliation, poster

I am presenting a poster at ICBC, which is sponsored by the IEEE Communications Society (ComSoc).
I am planning to use two logos for my poster.

I am considering the logos of the following:

1. The research organization. The presented research is from researchers of this organisation.
2. ICBC, the conference organizer
3. IEEE Communications Society (ComSoc), the conference sponsor
4. Logo of ICBC and IEEE, indicating both organizer and sponsor.

   Which two logos are suitable for the poster presentation.

Comment: Why do you need a logo?

Comment: And why do you need two specifically?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The logos on your poster should indicate the author's affiliation.  Use the logo of the presenting author's university.

Never use the organizer, sponsor, or host logo unless you work for them.  People attending the conference already know what conference they are at.  This information is not needed on a poster.

Comment: so, I have to put only one logo and that is my organization logo?

Comment: @Gopal ojha You don't *have to* use any logo, unless your organization wants you to.

Comment: *The logos on your poster should indicate the author's affiliation. Use the logo of the presenting author's university.* And/or unit logo, depending on how your lab is organized.

Comment: And your university/institution probably has "official" logos to be used for such purposes, and probably a style guide as well which describes how to use it, etc.  Worth reaching out to your uni's "communications" office, etc.

Comment: Unless, of course, you need to submit the poster as an "outcome" to your funding body, in which case a logo of the host may be a much needed evidence to justify the travel costs.

Answer (score 12):

Well, I'm *against* the overusage of logos, especially sponsor logos. There is already a big trend of forcing sponsor logos everywhere, including peer reviewed articles.

So please, do not support logo frenzy. If you insist on a logo, use the one that identifies you as the author, i.e., your department or your university logo.

Answer (score 4):

The norm is to include the logo of researcher’s organization for sure.  Apart from that, you might also want to include the logo for your funding agency or organization.  Any other logos you might want to include can go at the bottom of your posters, such as the logos for your collaborators’ institute, any specific facility you used for data generation or analysis etc.

Answer (score 3):

An approach I've often used is to use my institution's logo at the top on one side and on the other side either:

- The (only) collaborating institution.  The point of this is to reinforce the joint nature of the work. *Or*
- A group logo (for partial visual symmetry).

This seems to work well visually, and satisfies the corporate identity requirements that the university would like to impose without being too onerous. It wouldn't work as well for a large collaboration, unless the collaboration had its own logo to go in the second place.

Acknowledgements could be made in the form of logos, and some funders like it.  THese would be in an acknowledgements section at the bottom, and fairly small.

Conference logos are a waste of space *at the conference*.  If you plan to reuse the poster internally after the conference (many places put them on the wall outside the lab, for example) it may be worth including the conference logo and month/year, but again fairly small and at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

From the top of my head I can only come up with 2 legitimate use cases for logos in posters:

1. **Representation:** Do advertising for your affiliations, i.e. your university/institution and/or department. The reasoning behind that is to make it crystal clear and immediately recognizable where you work.
2. **Acknowledgement:** If your work is sponsored by some 3rd party or your project is part of a larger collaboration (like an ERC project or something of that sort) and they want you to graphically acknowledge them.

Logos are neither design (functional elements and/or considerations for making the material more easily accessible to your audience) nor decoration (elements that make your material look more aesthetically pleasing).

Typically you are not in full liberty to choose what logos you should have, institutions have a graphical policies clearly stating what rules you should go by when it comes to that sort of stuff. Also note that in some conferences the amount of logos that are to be present on posters may be limited.

PS: my definitions of design and decoration above are quite rudimentary but should hopefully convey the difference between the concepts. I once saw a great presentation on that but can't seem to find it now.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment of logos. Logos allow the reader to quickly determine the affiliation of the authors or funder at a distance. That's why they exist not only on posters but on everyday objects. They are more distinctive than "University of Somewhere, Sometown". They also serve as decoration by adding color and empty space to perhaps a wall of text.

Comment: @user71659 they do, hence the first use case mentioned above. I am not advocating for not using logos, what i am trying to say is this, the university or department logo belongs on the poster like your name does. Not to look pretty